# vimdiff and move among left and right pane

Tags: vim, cygwin, vimdiff

I am using `vimdiff` for the first time. Online I found written that to move from the left pane you use `CTRL + w + Left or right arrow`
This does not work for me. But I see that if I press just `CTRL + w` and press `w` for a sec and let it go, it switches pane after ~500ms.
Is this how it is supposed to work? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please read [`:h window-move-cursor`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window-move-cursor).

Comment: Its not supposed to be that slow. The lag on my set up is unnoticeable. Also you can use <Ctrl-W> h or l to move left or right.

Comment: please check if you have mapping with `ctrl-w w x y z`

Comment: @FDinoff:I tried <Ctrl-W> h but it does not work (at least in my cygwin)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`Ctrl+w` and right and left arrow can be used to move between any split windows on vim, not only vimdiff splits.

These keys do work here on cygwin; also, `Ctrl+w w` also moves to the next window, but without the delay you mentioned.

It is possible that you have mapped these keys in your .vimrc or via some vim plugin. You can check this with `:map w`, `:map <left>` and `:map <right>`.

As moving between windows is something that you use often, you may consider using the following mappings:

```
  nnoremap <C-J> <C-W>j
  nnoremap <C-K> <C-W>k
  nnoremap <C-H> <C-W>h
  nnoremap <C-L> <C-W>l
```

Then you can use `Ctrl+h` and `Ctrl+l` to move left and right, without moving your hands from the home row. And the `nnoremap` will ensure that these works despite of any other mappings that you may have.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this option. VSCode makes ctrl+w unusable so these mappings helped a lot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73749376/vscode-how-to-switch-window-in-vimdiff-as-ctrlw-closes-the-window

Answer (score 20):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and then (after releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>) press the arrow keys to change the pane.

Answer (score 9):

It is very useful to use `set mouse=a` in your `.vimrc` file. It gives you possibility to switch between windows using mouse. Additionally you can resize windows using it.

If you prefer to use keyboard I have also mapped arrow keys in `.vimrc` in this way:

```
map <C-Left> <C-W>j
map <C-Down> <C-W>k
map <C-Up> <C-W>h
map <C-Right> <C-W>l
```

Comment: Grzegorz, thanks for the tip.For me **set mouse=a** worked but **set mouse=a'** showed an error.

Comment: It was typo. It should be mouse=a

Comment: what's the reverse of 'set mouse=a'? I forgot.

Comment: oh it was `set mouse=`

Comment: @GrzegorzBielański  Hi, how am I use the keyboard with the .vimrc setting above? can I move the center divider left or right using keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `:wincmd w` for next window, and `:wincmd W` for previous window.

The `:wincmd` is especially useful when `ctrl+w` is captured by the environment. For example see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73749587/811335

Answer (score 0):

To move among left and right pane, Press ctrl+w and then ctrl+r. This is both left and right vice-versa.

Comment: This is for window rotation, not for moving between windows. `:h ctrl-w_ctrl-r` : "Rotate windows downward/rightwards. ... The cursor remains in the same window."

Answer (score 0):

Please go to differ line and do "dp" from left to right and "do" from right to left