# vscode: how to switch window in vimdiff as ctrl+w closes the window

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, vimdiff

I'm using `vimdiff` from VSCode's bash terminal. How do I go to the other window in vimdiff. Typically ctrl+w + right/left arrow is used to switch from one side to another. But VSCode capture ctrl+w and closes the window.

I'm using VSCode with remote `ssh` so using vimdiff from terminal is a whole lot of hassle as I'll have to set up another `ssh` session from local machine which is Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to switch windows in `vimdiff` because you have `:help :diffget` (or `:help do`), to "get" a given change from a given window, and `:help :diffput` (or `:help dp`), to "put" a given change *to* a given window.

If you still need to switch windows, you can use `:help :wincmd` to do so from the command line:

:wincmd w    " switch to next window
:wincmd W    " switch to previous window

Comment: I'm using vimdiff to see the differences and search for text on either side. Agreed that for editing `do` and `dp` are sufficient.

Comment: `:wincmd ` is helpful. Thanks!